# Android USB API: Switch between charge and data send

Tags: android, api, usb, arduino

I'm starting to use the Android USB API to send data from an Arduino to an Android device. Is it possible to programmatically switch between send/receive data and just charge the Android phone?

I know that you cannot do both things at the same time, and, since you have to open a `FileInputStream` in order to be able to receive data, as long as this is open the device won't be charged.

Will it be just as simple as closing this stream to charge again? If is as simple as it, can the Arduino then send basic information in order to ask the device to open the stream again?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I understand your concern or not. To charge and communicate through USB at the same time, you can use OTG. Here is link from Amazon, I shared: [https://www.amazon.com/Micro-Cable-Samsung-Player-OTHERS/dp/B00CXAC1ZW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CXAC1ZW)
I used it in one of my projects, it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, so that you can communicate with with other devices with your Android device you have to use an [OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) cable or adapter, which already predisposes the device so that it is in communication mode, also the Android USB api is already provided for this and you you have no need to manipulate this because the change of automatic