# Android USB Roles when Charging + Transmitting Data

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

I am aiming to be able to send a small chunk of data from a USB accessory to an Android phone, after the accessory is enumerated (in other words, on connection). The USB accessory is a charger which we will be designing.

As I understand:

1. The USB host is the one enumerating the devices, so that would have to be the Android device. But could the USB master be the one consuming the power?
2. If not, then if the Android device is acting as an accessory, could it be the one polling data?
3. If so, am I actually using USB OTG or not?
4. Would the accessory need to comply with Android Open Accessory specification to do such a thing?
5. Since it is sending the data on connection, I wouldn't be going into [charging + sending data issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200334/android-usb-api-switch-between-charge-and-data-send), right?

References I've been reading:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html